# Can I access the value of a previous lambda in a stream chain?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have this stream code, which does not compile:

```
itemList.stream()
    .map(im -> item2dogsMap.get(im.getEan()))
    .flatMap(List<Dog>::stream)
    .forEach(d -> System.out.println("item" + im + " with dog " + d));
```

The problem is that in the `forEach` statement I need `im` and `d`. But it cannot resolve `im` here.

I could create an `ItemAndDog` class taking the two values and do a new in the `map` statement. But that looks like overkill to me. Is there a way to do this without creating an extra class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not.
If you convert your lambdas to anonimous inner classes, you will see, the variables which you wanted to use are out of scope.

Answer (score 6):

You can solve the problem creating the resulting string inside the `flatMap` where you will have an access to both variables like this:

```
itemList.stream()
    .flatMap(im -> item2dogsMap.get(im.getEan()).stream()
        .map(d -> "item" + im + " with dog " + d))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: As this will produce a correct output it's not the same. This is actually creating creating a stream within a stream instead of one flattened stream. As soon you start using parallel streams this will matter a lot.

Comment: @BetaRide, have you actually tried? It's perfectly legit and parallel-compatible use of stream API. Just try.